How to quickly replace specific content when comparing two files?
In Visual Studio Code, when I am comparing two files, my screen may look like the following. In the image example, I want to keep lines 31 content on the left, and use it on the right at line 33.

Based on the screenshot above, is there a keyboard shortcut, or a keyboard binding configuration I can setup, that will allow me to quickly replace a desired selection, e.g. only line 33 in the right side window, with the values from line 31 on the left side?

As of v1.88.1, there is a button, but there doesn't seem to be a keyboard shortcut or command.
In side-by-side view
Click Revert block in the middle bar. This button is normally an arrow that shows up when you either hover over the middle bar or select the right/new/green line. It can also be an ellipsis when the changed line is the first in the file, which opens a context menu where you can click Revert block.


In inline view
Click the left/old/red line then Revert this change. Or you can click Revert block (the fishhook) in the side bar.


